# Is f(n) = 1000n + 4500lgn + 54n O(n)?

Tags: math, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I was given the following question in my test:

> Is f(n) = 1000n + 4500lgn + 54n O(n)?

I answered this question by applying the following definition:

> Definition of O(n), which is that for some function f(n) there must be two positive constants, c and k, such that c > 0, k > 0, n >= k, and 0 <= f(n) <= cn. If we can show that constants c and k exist then the function is O(n) (and if those constants don't exist then the function is actually larger than O(n)).

Solution:

0 ≤ 1000n + 4500lgn + 54n ≤ cn
0 ≤ 4000 + 9000 + 216 ≤ 4c when k=4
0 ≤ 3304 ≤ c

0 ≤ 8000 + 13500 + 432 ≤ 8n when n=8>k
0 ≤ 21932 ≤ 8n
0 ≤ 2741.5 ≤ n (last time c=3304 but now it is 2741.5....as n increases, c is not constant!)

Conclusion:
This function is not O(n) - we can't find constant values c and k because they simply don't exist.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: I assume "lgn" means log(n)?

Comment: yes, it is log based 2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may be more appropriate on [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6):

> 0 ≤ 2741.5 ≤ n (last time c=3304 but now it is 2741.5....as n increases, c is not constant!)

The flaw in your solution is that if you stick with the original value of `c`, the constraint is still satisfied.  It is not the actual value of the constants that matters, simply that there exists a pair of constants `c` and `k` for which the inequality is satisfied *for all `n > k`*.

I don't know what level of rigor is required (by your teachers) in an answer to that question.  However, a rigorous solution would require a mathematical proof (from first principles or established theorems) that either `c` and `k` do exist<sup>1</sup>, or that they cannot exist.

---

<sup>1 - A pair of `c` and `k` that you can *prove* does satisfy the constraint *for all `N > k`* would be a sufficient proof.</sup>

Comment: Yes .... it is.  For any +ve constants `C1` & `C2`, there will be a `K` such that if `N > K`, then `|C1 * N| > |C2 * log(N)|`.  The result for your `f(N)` follows from that.

Answer (score 4):

log<sub>2</sub>n < n, so 1000n + 4500 log<sub>2</sub>n + 54n ≤ 1000n + 4500n + 54n.

Just add up the coefficients. For `k = 1` and `c = 1000 + 4500 + 54 = 5554`, `f(n) ≤ c*n` for all `n ≥ k`. Therefore `f` is `O(n)`.